# html data trimmed in output pdf using angular fspdf

Tags: angular, jspdf

I need to covert one html table data to pdf file am using jspdf for it, the file is downloading but the table data is trimmed of from right hand side

```
<table #content>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Pin</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Alfreds</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

 @ViewChild('content', {static: false}) content: ElementRef;

makepdf() {
let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.html(this.content.nativeElement, {
  callback: (pdf) => {
    pdf.save('outputfile');
    },
  });
}

  How to display the entire table content inside PDF file?
```